# Prevent user from Single Sing On Office365/Gsuite

Tags: ms-office, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, federated-identity, google-workspace

I have changed the authentication type for my domain (in google and office) from **managed** to **federated authentication**, in order to enable single sign on with third party.

I want to create new users in (office/google) with normal authentication. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, change to `Managed` mode, add users and then change back to `Federated`.

The reason why MSFT doesn't allow this because,

- If we enable `Federated` mode, that mean the users are living in on-prem (at your company security domain).
- If we enable `Managed` mode, that mean the users are living in AzureAD domain.

So that's the reason, MSFT doesn't allow user creation when in `Federated` mode.

Cmdlets goes like this:

```
$dom = "example.com"
Set-MsolDomainAuthentication –DomainName $domain -FederationBrandName $dom -Authentication Managed
<Add Users>
Set-MsolDomainAuthentication –DomainName $domain -FederationBrandName $dom -Authentication Federated
```

Comment: Thank you @Zeigeist  ,i have aanothe question If i have create one user in federated mode is it possible to convert it to managed mode ?

Comment: What about Gsuite do you have any idea how i can execute those commands ?

Comment: If you create an user in managed mode, that can be used for managed and federation flows, and not the other the way (i.e., you can't create user in AzureAD if mode is federated). I'm not sure about GSuite.

Comment: If my response seems correct to you, please mark as answer and vote. That way, it help others to look into the solution.